# PHP PEAR Container error

Tags: php, email, pear, mail-queue

Allrighty, it's the first time I ask a question here. My problem is as awkward as it is difficult to get to the bottom of.
Story goes like this: I have this little system, which sends alot of e-mail invitations(not spam). So, being sensible, I don't use the PHP function mail(),
I use PEAR classes like Mail, Mail_Queue, Net_SMTP, etc.
Only problem is, my error logs fill up with tons of errors like this:

```
PHP Notice:  Error in sending mail: 
Mail Queue Error: Cannot initialize container in /usr/lib/php/PEAR.php on line 873
```

And then, of course:

```
[18-Feb-2011 17:38:44] PHP Fatal error:  
Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 3 bytes) in /usr/lib/php/PEAR.php on line 844
```

Here's the code which inits the mail queue(inside a class called Newsletter)

```
//I know passing the DSN as the string is kind of deprecated, 
//but it;'s the only way it works on my system
$dsn ="mysql://$db_user:$db_pass@$db_host/$db_name";
$db_options = array();
$db_options['type']       = 'db';
$db_options['dsn']        = $dsn;
$db_options['mail_table'] = TABLE_QUEUE;

$this->host = '-- valid host here --';//data in these strings has been obscured
$this->username = '-- valid username here --';
$this->password = '-- valid password here --';

//optionally, a 'dns' string can be provided instead of db parameters.
//look at DB::connect() method or at DB or MDB docs for details.
//you could also use mdb container instead db
//$server = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']:'localhost';
$mail_options = array(
    'driver'   => 'smtp',
    'host'     => $this->host,
    'port'     => 25,
    'auth'     => true,
    'username' => $this->username,
    'password' => $this->password,
);
$this->mail_queue = new Mail_Queue($db_options, $mail_options);
```

Some more code down the line,

```
public function sendChunk($start, $count)
{
    global $db;
    $ids = $db->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT id_user as id FROM ".TABLE_QUEUE);
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($ids as $id)
        $ret[] = $id->id;
    unset($ids);        
    $this->mail_queue->sendMailsInQueue($count, $start, 1);
    return true;
}
```

Problem is, I double checked every line of code I wrote, and it's doing it's job. Only problem is that sometimes it refuses to send any mails.
Thanks in advance for replies.

Comment: Possibly something inside the mail_queue is building up over time and sucking up all the available memory. Instead of using the same object throughout the entire mail run, try switching to creating a new mail_queue after a certain number of emails have been sent? That should flush whatever's building up and release some memory periodically.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) instead of DB

```
$db_options['type']       = 'db';
```

to

```
$db_options['type']       = 'mdb2';
```

this helped in taking care of  memory exhaust problem, I am still looking to take care of initialize container in `/usr/lib/php/PEAR.php` problem

Ok found the solution for container errors:
Apply this patch
http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/Mail_Queue/trunk/Mail/Queue.php?r1=303876&r2=309126

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to limit result. using limit in your select statement.
2. Try to flush the old main queye.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. Most of the time, even though i get tons of errors, there is only 1 email to send, and the queue is almost always empty. Oh, and btw, the SELECT statement is irrelevant, it was being used later on in a piece of code i cut out. My bad.